# react-native / expo / expo-google-app-auth vs expo-google-sign-in

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

Why does expo have two ways to authenticate with google?

It is not clear to me what the differences are between [expo-google-app-auth](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/) and [expo-google-sign-in](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/).

Which one should I use for what occasion?

Answer (score 5):

The difference is expo-google-sign-in is only available if you ejected your expo app (which is what "standalone" means) and you wouldn't need to leave your app and open a web browser to sign in.

If you want to keep using expo snack you would need to keep it from being ejected, so you should use expo-google-app-auth, which basically opens up a web browser to sign in, so it's less sophisicated than expo-google-sign-in option, but it's your only choice.

Comment: Incredibly enlightening! Do you know if there is an update on this matter? I couldn't find anything regarding a non-ejecting option.

Comment: You need to use expo-google-app-auth for non-ejecting option -- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/. The documentation here is a bit obtuse and it's actually been deprecated for authsessions (as noted and linked in the documentation)-- so I would recommend that except for some issues if you want to get both an apiToken and a jwt at the same time.